# Label doesn't change accordingly

Tags: ios, button, tags, label, viewcontroller

I got the following problem: The labels always change to the ones definied in tag 9001. Could someone help me spot my error?

ViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)switch0:(id)sender

{(button.tag = 9001);
UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
SecondViewController *second =[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil     bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
second.buttonTag  = buttonPressed.tag;
 }


- (IBAction)switch2:(id)sender2

{ (button2.tag = 9002); 
UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender2;
SecondViewController *third =[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:third animated:YES];
second.buttonTag  = buttonPressed.tag;
```

}

SecondViewcontroller.m

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

if (buttonTag == 9001) {
self.label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Radnomtext"];
self.label2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Randomtext"];
self.label3.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Randomtext?"];
}
if (buttonTag == 9002) {
self.label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Radnomtext2"];
self.label2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Randomtext2"];
self.label3.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Randomtext2?"];
```

Comment: I edited it to display the right code! THanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example and your presenting the view twice I took out the modal in this example:

```
   - (IBAction)switch0:(id)sender

    {
    UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
    SecondViewController *second =[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil     bundle:nil];

 NSInteger tagToSet = 9001;
    second.buttonTag  = tagToSet;;
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
     }
```

and using the keyword switch is no good. It is a reserved word in Objective C.

Comment: You need to set the tag before you push the view.

Comment: secondButton.tag = 9001; and secondButton.tag = 9002; before your view is pushed.

Comment: Your setting it to the senders tag, This is fine if you set the tags in interface builder or the storyboard.

Comment: See the edited code above and if you want a ModalView instead just change the push method to presentModalViewController:animated;

Comment: Thanks for the code, I implemented it, but sadly it still doesnt change to another label, except the one from 9001

Comment: Did you change both methods to this code? And only change the NSInteger to the number you want, 9001 or 9002? Another thing is the NibName:nil? why don't you put the name? @"SecondViewController" and one more thing make sure to set buttonTag in the secondViewController to nil in the ViewDidUnload.

Comment: Yeah I did both of those things. I put in the name also. In addition to that *buttonPressed is now an unsused variable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you forgot to close the ending bracket for first `if`?

```
if (buttonTag == 9001) {
    self.label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Radnomtext"];
    self.label2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Randomtext"];
    self.label3.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Randomtext?"];
} // bracket supposed to be here

if (buttonTag == 9002) {
```

or maybe you set `buttonTag` to incorrect instance?

```
- (IBAction)switch2:(id)sender2

{
UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender2;
SecondViewController *third =[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:third animated:YES];
second.buttonTag  = buttonPressed.tag; // supposed to be third?
[self.navigationController pushViewController:third animated:YES];
(button2.tag = 9002); 
}
```

And to be safe, you should set `buttonTag` before `presentModalViewController`.

Comment: Good eye man. I would thing there would have been some compiler warnings here.

Comment: It is in the compiler, I just forgot to copy it here. So that is (sadly) not the mistake, but thx for pointing it out :)

Comment: Thanks, I actually did forget that, still didnt do the trick. Also setting buttontag before the other did not help. :(

Comment: I noticed this also: sender2 should just be sender.